# Supported antenna for WiMax device

Tags: wireless

I would like to know which type of antenna can be used with WiMAX devices to have excellent connectivity.

I guess I have very normal one installed manufactured by ZTE.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

WiMAX antennas, just like the antennas for car radio, cell phone, FM radio, or TV, are designed to optimize performance for a given application. The figure above illustrates the three main types of antennas used in WiMAX deployments.

**Omni directional antennas**

Are used for point-to-multipoint configurations. The main drawback to an omni directional antenna is that its energy is greatly diffused in broadcasting 360 degrees. This limits its range and ultimately signal strength. Omni directional antennas are good for situations where there are a lot of subscribers located very close to the base station. An example of omni directional application is a WiFi hotspot where the range is less than 100 meters and subscribers are concentrated in a small area.

**Sector Antennas**

A sector antenna, by focusing the beam in a more focused area, offers greater range and throughput with less energy. Many operators will use sector  antennas to cover a 360-degree service area rather than use an omni directional antenna due to the superior per-formance of sector antennas over an omni directional antenna.

**Panel Antennas**

Panel antennas are usually a flat panel of about one foot square. They can also be a configuration where potentially the WiMAX radio is contained in the square antenna enclosure. Such configurations are powered via the Ethernet cable that connects the ra-dio/antenna combination to the wider network. That power source is known as Power over Ethernet (PoE). This streamlines deployments as there is no need to house the radio in a separate, weatherproof enclosure if outdoors or in a wiring closet if indoors. This configuration can also be very handy for relays.

For me I found Panel antenna is the most powerfull one If you know exaclty where is your Wimax bridge

The distance between My bridge and my Wimax antenna around 8 KM and works perfect with me

[image]

[Resources](http://www.teletopix.org/wimax/which-types-of-antennas-used-in-wimax/)

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I have Panel and would try switch to Sector

Comment: Are you Wimax provider?! read what I have said again :)

Comment: I am user and I was wondering if adding antenna to existing device would help to have excellent connectivity. I have a rectangular type of box installed similar to Panel antenna.